# How can I search two filters of propertyQuery in JIRA API search

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I tried with this link : https://path.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search?propertyQuery=%5Btags%5D.archived%3Dyes&propertyQuery=%5Bmembership%5D.index.63f330776bbd662d73f889af%3Dyes&properties=tags%2Cmembership&startAt=0&status=live, but I only get the first filter. If I take one it works.

- Also I tried to add "AND", but nothing.

a filter with propertyQuery to get properties archived and membership.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Jira doesn't support multiple properties set in `propertyQuery` https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/how-to-fetch-jira-projects-that-have-a-certain-project-property-set/36741/10

To make followup on implementation, refer to https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/ACJIRA-2667